Contradiction in Parashat Behukotai Blessings
In Parashat Behukotai it is written: "והשיג לכם דיש את בציר ובציר ישיג את זרע ואכלתם לחמכם לשובע..." (Your threshing shall overtake the vintage, and your vintage shall overtake the sowing; you shall eat your fill of bread and dwell securely in your land.)
According to the Mefarshim: "ואכלתם לחמם לשובע", means that you will not need to eat a lot for feeling satiated (be full of food). On the other hand, the other part of the verse, "והשיג לכם דיש את בציר ובציר ישיג את זרע", means that the land will yield a lot of production to harvest. This means that you will have to work continually to harvest the land production. But if we will feel satisfied with minimal amount of production, why would you need to work so hard to harvest, it does not seem blessing and seems to contradict the other part of the verse?

There will be extra to export; and everyone will be able to see that there's abundance.

The answer can be beautifully explained by analyzing the last bracha in that same verse:

וְהִשִּׂ֨יג לָכֶ֥ם דַּ֙יִשׁ֙ אֶת־בָּצִ֔יר וּבָצִ֖יר יַשִּׂ֣יג
אֶת־זָ֑רַע וַאֲכַלְתֶּ֤ם לַחְמְכֶם֙ לָשֹׂ֔בַע וִֽישַׁבְתֶּ֥ם לָבֶ֖טַח
בְּאַרְצְכֶֽם׃

On this the Ohr HaChaim HaKadosh comments:

עוד ירצה באומרו וישבתם לבטח פירוש שלא תטרחו אתם בקציר ובבציר אלא זרים
יעבודו ואתם יושבים בקתדרא, ואומרו לבטח שאין מיחוש על הקנין היותו ביד
עובדים:
Another aspect of the blessing contained in this verse is that
foreigners will perform the heavy labour in our country whereas the
Israelites will "sit securely in your land," not even worrying that
the foreign labourers may steal and cheat them out of their harvest.

So now it can be understood. The first part of the bracha is in regards to the land yielding in abundance. The second part of the bracha is that you will be satiated with little food. The last bracha is that even though the land will produce in abundance and require a lot of work, you will not need to be the ones to do it and can rely on foreign labour. It would then be seemingly logical that with all the “remaining” produce they will sell and therefore make a profit so all the brachas tie in quite nicely with the explanation from the Ohr HaChaim HaKadosh
See the Ohr HaChaim further on this same verse that also explains that this bracha, specifically of plentiful produce, will make the whole world recognize that the land of Israel belongs to us
